# Can I specify a "base package path" for a directory in Java?

Tags: java, directory, nested, classpath, package

If I have a Java package, for example:

```
package org.foo.bar.stuff;
```

I can store the source `.java` files in a directory `src/org/foo/bar/stuff`, given that I add `src/` to my classpath. In this example the directory contents tree is like this:

```
`-- src
    `-- org
        `-- foo
            `-- bar
                `-- stuff
                    |-- ICat.java
                    `-- IMouse.java
```

If I could define a "base" package name, eg. `org.foo.bar` for a *directory* like `/stuff`, the tree could become like this:

```
`-- src
    `-- stuff  # has defined base "org.foo.bar"
        |-- ICat.java
        `-- IMouse.java
```

**Is there technically a way to define a "base" package name, ie. `org.foo.bar`, for a *directory* like `/stuff`, in order to avoid nested directories?**

Comment: No. But you could use inner classes to achieve something similar.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch wouldn't that change access modifiers or information hiding? Could you give an example?

Comment: @Chris It would be convenient for me to work "my way" and transform the tree to the standard structure when publishing. However useful the nested directories are for disambiguity in the end, they are an annoyance to work with (even IDEs like Eclipse group them).

Comment: It still sounds like you're working around the real problem. Eclipse has an option to concat empty directories into one line.

Comment: @Chris yes I mean the same by "grouping", I think. The real problem is that I was interested if there are other convenient ways to browse the source tree other than an IDE, ie. shell/command line, [mc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander), standard utils, whatever. I mean I could just use the IDE if there aren't any options but it's worth to ask.

Comment: @naxa The entire Java ecosystem is built around the standard file/package structure. You're going to be fighting every tool you use if you want to have your "own way", and it's better to learn the (quite easy) tools to navigate the standards: they were developed for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the Java specification doesn't enforce it, all well-known compilers use directory structures. The specification explicitly states a database for storage of classes, which wouldn't use any directories at all.

Short answer: If you're using standard Java tools, you can't avoid nested directories.

> [7.2. Host Support for Packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.2)
>
> Each host system determines how packages and compilation units are
>   created and stored.
>
> ...
>
> In simple implementations of the Java SE platform, packages and
>   compilation units may be stored in a local file system. Other
>   implementations may store them using a distributed file system or some
>   form of database.
>
> If a host system stores packages and compilation units in a database,
>   then the database must not impose the optional restrictions (§7.6) on
>   compilation units permissible in file-based implementations.
>
> ...
>
> Systems that use a database must, however, provide an option to
>   convert a program to a form that obeys the restrictions, for purposes
>   of export to file-based implementations.

(It sounds like you're working around the real problem.)

Comment: I see. I'm not trying to optimize, it would be just a temporary transformation. See my comment. I guess I just could rename the whole package temprarily then. :)

Comment: For enlonging the answer, are you by chance familiar with the part of the JLS that defines this?

Comment: @naxa: Great question. The specification isn't as strict on the storage as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to do this, I do not necessarily endorse it.
If (for some reason) you don't want to nest your classes into packages, you could nest your classes in your classes (if you really want)...

```
package it.is.a;

public class Demo {
  public static class A {}
  public static class B {}
}
```

Then `it.is.a.Demo.A` and `it.is.a.Demo.B` are grouped with `Demo`.

Comment: Does this play well with imports?

Comment: While this would solve the stated problem, you don't really think this is a good idea, do you? ;)